# How save an layer styles as Default in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap

is there any way to save the layer styles as default in ArcMap?

Comment: For a specific Feature Class?

Comment: for example i have a db like test.gdb with 5 layers ,,i want to applay some styles and save as default ,,when am open that db in any arcmap it shud display that saved default stlles..is this posible?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to improve it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to save layer styles and open it with the same layers "as default".

But you can:

1. Create Map Package (Package will contain your symbology and data layers)
   http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//006600000403000000
2. Change standard symbology to Cartographic Representations
   http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/What_are_representations/00s50000004m000000/
3. Save symbology as .lyr, and import it for every layer

Comment: Concerning 3: you can use "apply symbology from layer" to assign an existing layer style (from either a .lyr file or a layer in your table of content) to other layers